# Finding a formula for drawing an Arc after moving the starting point

Tags: math, geometry, gis, computational-geometry, google-earth

I'm trying to program a formula to calculate the new angle when drawing an Arc. It might be better if I explained it with a picture.

[image: Picture of question]

Above is a picture of what I'm drawing on google earth.

Currently I have a function that draws an Arc given a (x,y) pivot point, the bearing and the distance of the radius

After drawing this Arc (which is the farthest Arc from the origin) on the plot, I need to move the origin point, eg. If bearing was 170 degrees, the left line would start at 170-90 and the right one at 170+90

I'm having trouble finding out the formula for the angle (or bearing) that is in the smaller concentric circles. I would like to thank anyone in advance for any help that you can provide.

Here is my formula for calculating and drawing an Arc

```
def drawArc(lat1,lon1,lbearing,rbearing,hr): #draw Arc given lat/lon piviot point with the right and left bearing to draw the path and distance
    arcstr=""
    if rbearing < lbearing: #if the left bearing is already bigger than the right bearing, switch places. Test Case not proven yet! with winds coming from the east
        lbearing,rbearing = rbearing,lbearing
    while lbearing < rbearing:
        arc1,arc2 = getEndpoint(lat1,lon1,lbearing,hr) #arc1 and arc2 are lat and lon respectively 
        arcCoord = "%f,%f,0\n"%(arc2,arc1)
        arcstr+=arcCoord
        lbearing+=1 #count
    #attach the last remaining point which is the end point at the right bearing
    arc1,arc2 = getEndpoint(lat1,lon1,rbearing,hr) #arc1 and arc2 are lat and lon respectively 
    arcCoord = "%f,%f,0\n"%(arc2,arc1)
    arcstr+=arcCoord
    return arcstr
```

To draw the three Arcs, here is where the function is called:

```
arc3=drawArc(latitude,longitude,leBearing,reBearing,arc3hr)
arc2=drawArc(latitude,longitude,leBearing-(SOME FORMULA TO GIVE ME THE EXTRA ANGLE/BEARING TO INTERSECT WITH THE OUTER LINE),reBearing+(SAME FORMULA HERE),arc2hr) 
arc1=drawArc(latitude,longitude,leBearing-(SOME FORMULA TO GIVE ME THE EXTRA ANGLE/BEARING TO INTERSECT WITH THE OUTER LINE),reBearing+(SAME FORMULA HERE),arc1hr)
```

Known Points on this picture:

1. Origin point in lat/lon
2. Distance and bearing of each line
3. Radius of Inner Circle at origin is 10 NM and outer circle is 20NM

Here is a simplified picture, I believe angle theta is what I'm looking for

[image: simplified]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not actually a programming problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the necessary geometry, assuming I interpreted your description and picture correctly. The image below (and [linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxal3.jpg)) shows your picture with the variables we need to solve for theta.

[image: picture]

Now, the math. This makes use of the law of [sines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofSines.html)/[cosines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html).

Law of cosines gives us:

[image]

So we must solve for h, g, and f and then take the inverse cosine of the result to get theta.

[image]

[image]

And by law of sines...

[image]

We can solve for a immediately with law of cosines:

[image]

To find the lengths of segments x_1 and x_2, we need the angles theta_1,2,3...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using these angles and more law of sines gives us x_1 and x_2...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Put this all together and you get

[image]

Just take [image] of this mess after substituting the proper value for [image] which depends on your choice of d (or DIST). I won't bother writing it here.